# looking for simple logger that write to file and console

Tags: node.js, typescript

I new on nodejs and typescript.

I writing the first server on nodejs (this code is implemented using typescripts) now and i need to have on my server a logger that write to file and to console.

I google it and all what i found was JavaScript logger and this is not working with typescript.

Comment: This is a really incomplete question. Please mention what logging package you're trying to use, show how you're importing/requiring it, how it's configured, how you're calling the logging functions and what errors you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morgan is pretty simple to use, for example (through express) :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan

Console :

```
var express = require('express')
var morgan = require('morgan')

var app = express()

app.use(morgan('combined'))

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello, world!')
})
```

Files :

```
var express = require('express')
var fs = require('fs')
var morgan = require('morgan')
var path = require('path')

var app = express()

// create a write stream (in append mode) 
var accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 
'access.log'), {flags: 'a'})

// setup the logger 
app.use(morgan('combined', {stream: accessLogStream}))

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello, world!')
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend Winston.Add winston to your project by installing it. Then add winston to your project : 
`const winston = require('winston')

winston.log('info', 'Hello logs!')`
This will log following to stdout --- info:Hello logs!

To write in files you can do in following way :

```
var access = fs.createWriteStream(dir + '/node.my.log', { flags: 'a' })
          , error = fs.createWriteStream(dir + '/node.err.log', { flags: 'a' });

    proc.stdout.pipe(my);
    proc.stderr.pipe(err);
```

Comment: There is no `require` in typescript. use `import ... from ...` instead.